# Local Angular library using Highcharts breaks in production mode

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-library

I wrote an Angular library wrapping Highcharts to fit my needs.

When using it locally in dev mode it runs well, but the optimization of the prod mode seems to break it.

The problem comes from the Highcharts module needed to add some features, for example to add new chart types (ie TreeMap). These modules seems not to be loaded in prod mode, resulting in a Highcharts error (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/).

This is my first Angular library so the config must be wrong but I can't find where the problem is.

I pushed a minimal reproduction of the problem in this repo: https://github.com/Korbraan/angular-library-opti-bug

First build the library with `ng build charts`, then try serving it with  `ng serve --prod`. It breaks, but it works with `ng serve`.

Comment: I've tested it. In the development mode as well in production there is the same error: `Cannot find module '../../../../dist/charts' -> import { TreeMapModule } from '../../../../dist/charts';`

Comment: The library needs to be built before the application is served, I add the command in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you have to move modules initialization inside the constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    Treemap(self.Highcharts);
    Heatmap(self.Highcharts);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you it works!
Why do the modules need to be instantiated in the constructor here?

Why is it better to use callbackFunction than the chartInstance event?

Comment: I've no idea why, yet it works. Check this related thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/138. `chartInstance` event has been added to the wrapper and I didn't know it exists. It works the same as `callbackFunction` so your code was valid, my mistake.